# Script to change UI alignment

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

Suppose I have 2 text fields in a Java Swing file. I need to add a third field on top of the other two, then modify the alignment of the original two fields.

I am looking for some script or runtime classes which will dynamically change the alignment according to this requirement.

`a1.setBounds(264,`**619**`+132,200,n);`

`a2.setBounds(264,`**641**`+132,200,n);`

`a3.setBounds(264,`**663**`+132,200,n);`

If I want to add one field on top then I need to change all the below coordinates. So I need something like a script that will pass the X or Y coordinates value (suppose n) and the fields below will modify accordingly.

Comment: The script you are looking for is using a layout manager instead of setting bounds manually. That will do the job for you. For that particular setup, also consider using `JList`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that I never user `setBounds(...)` since I always use a LayoutManager.  However, I don't know your situation so I won't judge.  Okay. maybe a little: USE A LAYOUT MANAGER!

Anyhoo, changing the `magic numbers` to something like this and you'll be able to add as many as you like w/o having to renumber everything.

[Untested, but you should get the idea]

```
const int yOffset = 22;
int yStart = 619;
int row = 0;

a1.setBounds(264, (yStart + (yOffset * row++)) + 132, 200, n);
a2.setBounds(264, (yStart + (yOffset * row++)) + 132, 200, n);
a3.setBounds(264, (yStart + (yOffset * row++)) + 132, 200, n);
```